# TouchBarServer not working, SIGSTOP error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

The Touch Bar on my MacBook Pro 15'' 2019 is not working anymore after upgrading to Ventura. I have tried all solutions and fixes online about the Touch Bar not working, to no avail. As a last resort I ran the process through a debugger. The `TouchBarServer` process returns a `SIGSTOP`. I have run the process through `lldb` and this is the output:

```
(lldb) process attach --pid 341
Process 341 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'com.apple.touchbarserver.main', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007ff817ae15c2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg2_trap + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg2_trap:
->  0x7ff817ae15c2 <+10>: retq   
    0x7ff817ae15c3 <+11>: nop    

libsystem_kernel.dylib`macx_swapon:
    0x7ff817ae15c4 <+0>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7ff817ae15c7 <+3>:  movl   $0x1000030, %eax          ; imm = 0x1000030 
Target 0: (TouchBarServer) stopped.
Executable module set to "/usr/libexec/TouchBarServer".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx-.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What if you boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac).  Usually when something like this "stops" in this manner, you might be looking at a hardware issue